# Semaphore simple sample

Tags: java, multithreading

Can anyone share simple sample of using Semaphore?
If it's possible a sample of solving a task without semaphore and then with semaphore to understand main idea of it.

Comment: The javaDoc of `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` has an example. (and google has some more, btw: *semaphore example java*)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a simple Semaphore implementation:

```
public class Semaphore {
  private boolean signal = false;

  public synchronized void take() {
    this.signal = true;
    this.notify();
  }

  public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{
    while(!this.signal) wait();
    this.signal = false;
  }

}
```

The `take()` method sends a signal which is stored internally in the Semaphore. The `release()` method waits for a signal. When received the signal flag is cleared again, and the `release()` method exited.

Read [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html) and take a look at this [example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-11/02-qa-semaphore.html)