# Use multi-threading to calculate sum of 10 thousand integers in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, synchronized

I want to use multi-threading to calculate the sum of 10 thousand integers (from 1 to 10000). I have the basic understanding of synchronized key work. I know synchronized allows only one thread at a time during the execution and semaphore allows a certain number of threads at a time.

Here is my implementation using synchronized keyword:

```
public class Testing {
private static int sum = 0;
private static int one = 1;
public synchronized static void increment() {
    sum = sum + one;
    one++;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();;
    t2.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

**My solution**: Divide the 10 thousand number into two parts. Use two threads to calculate each part.

**Question**: Is there a better way to do that by using semaphore? I used synchronized here but should we use semaphore? How should we use semaphore to improve in this case?

Comment: `IntStream.range(1, 10001).parallel().sum()`

Comment: Please see my edit @shmosel

Comment: You could always split them down to more than 2 threads, say 100 and merge up the solutions. Similar to merge sort maybe.

Comment: You don't need synchronization or semaphores. There's no point in multithreading at all if the threads have to synchronize on their sole task.

Comment: @shmosel you are wrong, both threads are reading and writing the variable "sum" and "one". If I did not use synchronized keyword, the sum would sometimes not equal to that result.

Comment: @SHE that's exactly your mistake. They should be keeping separate variables and merging when they're done.

Comment: I try practicing and understanding the synchronized and semaphore, so I implement it in this way. @shmosel

Comment: If you want mutual exclusion, you probably should use `synchronized` blocks (simple, foolproof), or you should use `ReentrantLock` (more powerful).  `Semaphore` is an ancient idea that once was proposed as a primitive mechanism upon which synchronization objects could be built, but now it is implemented _on top of_ different, more modern primitives.  It's mostly obsolete.  The library provides it in case you want to implement algorithms from twenty and thirty year old text books.

Comment: alright @jameslarge

Comment: Nothing wrong with practicing and understanding `synchronized` and etc., but don't overlook @shmosel's advice:  A program that can _reliably_ demonstrate how `synchronized` protects data is a program that has a _lot_ of collisions between threads trying to access the protected data.  But, when you're trying to solve real problems, a program that has a lot of collisions between threads is a Bad Program.  In real-world situtations, we try to minimize how often threads need to enter synchronized blocks, and we try to minimize the amount of time that the threads spend in there.

Comment: Though your question may be useful to you specifically for practice, it isn't very useful for the community at large in terms of sharing best practices, which is what this site is all about.  @shmosel's comments on the other hand offer more practical advice for anyone seeking the best/simplest/most efficient way to tackle this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to sum a no of integers instead look at [ForkJoinTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html)

If you are trying to understand semaphore usage check [Semaphore simple sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868363/semaphore-simple-sample)

**EDIT:**
change your increment() to

```
public static void increment() 
    {
        try
        {
            semaphore.acquire();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            //process excp
        }
        sum = sum + one;
        one++;
        semaphore.release();
    }
```

and add

```
private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

as class variable

But as others have noted this is not the right way to split the problem.
*Also, if you are looking for wait()/notify() semaphore model, you'd still have to use synchronized.*

Comment: If you can show me how semaphore applies to this case, that would be extremely helpful. @SVasisth

Comment: excellent! can you show me an example of semaphore with size 2 or 3? @SVashisth